# Google Drive API v3 fields missing while all fields are selected

Tags: java, google-drive-api

I have an application that calls the Google Drive API v3.
Here is the call:

```
List<File> files = service.files().list().setFields("nextPageToken, files(*)").execute().getFiles();
```

Mostly I want to work with the file permissions, but I noticed that several Permission fields are null, for example the getPermissionDetails() call always returns null.

I also tried getting the permission list with all existing fields:

```
PermissionList filePermissions = service.permissions().list(fileID).setFields("permissions(*)").execute();
```

but the permission details are still null for every single permission.
Is it possible that these values are really null and won't ever get retrieved?

Comment: This is a problem because I want to be able to tell if the permission is inherited or not, and this field is contained in the PermissionDetails field.

Comment: Have you tried using the [Try this API](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions/list) feature for these files? Do you still get `null` responses?

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try. In the meantime I found that there is only one permissionId per user, so it probably won't matter whether in that specific instance it is inherited or not.